# How to fetch data from table in model in larvel framework and directly use in view?

Tags: laravel, view, model

I have created a model like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class countData extends Model
{
    //
    public function countAbc () {

        // i don't know how to write in laravel query so for understanding purpose i wrote in simple pg query
        $sql=pg_query("select count(*) as countrow from s_abc");
        $countfetch=pg_fetch_array($sql);
        return $countfetch[0];
    }
}
```

I don't have any route for this function. On view page I am check

```
@if( $Item->ClassID == 'abc' )
{
//then call the above model and use countAbc () function
countAbc();
}
```

Basically my view is already loaded, I need to check the condition and call the above model to count the data.

Comment: I think you need to know how to create and define a [model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Comment: Basically how to fetch data from database in model and use in view without creating any route

Comment: It seems u have a table `s_abc`, so you can define a model name `SAbc`.  So you can count this table's data.

Comment: yes exactly. Means I have to create a model with same name of my table name?

Comment: yes. So you can do something like this:`$countrow = SAbc::count()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for helper function.

In question you've created `countAbc()` function and you want to call it everywhere.

Use to make function in `helpers.php` file instead of `model file`

Create a `helpers.php` file in your app folder and load it up with composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php" // <---- ADD THIS
    ]
},
```

After adding that to your `composer.json` file, run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Afterward, put your this function in `helpers.php`

```
public function countAbc () {
        $sql=pg_query("select count(*) as countrow from s_abc");
        $countfetch=pg_fetch_array($sql);
        return $countfetch[0];
}
```

Now, You can access it anywhere.

```
public function countAbc () {
        $counts_abc = \DB::table('s_abc')->count();
        return $counts_abc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model that corresponds to the table:

```
php artisan make:model Sabc
```

Open that model file, and set the table name:

```
protected $table = 's_abc';
```

If you want to get the count of the amount of rows within your table that corresponds to the model, it's simple:

```
Sabc::count();
```

Answer (score 0):

First Of All I think you have to look Laravel Framework structure: [Laravel Directory Structure And contents inside it](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/structure).

Basically you don't have to define route to fetch data from database.
You have to define model properly - long story short every table in your database have to have one model in your app.

You have tablse `s_abc` You have to define model `SAbc`.

`php artisan make:model SAbc` - this command will make model for you.

After that you can use Eloquent aggregate functions to get count or you can write your own method in it:

#### Using Aggregate function:

```
...
use App\SAbc;
...
class SomeClass {
    ...
    $count_sabc = SAbc::count();
    ...
}
...
```

#### Using Your Own Method

In your model write:

```
...
class SAbc extends Model {
    public function getCount() {
        return self::count();
        // Or with raw query
        // return self::selectRaw('count(*) as count')->first()->count
    }
}
...

// Then you can use this methd anywhere you want like that:
(new SAbc)->getCount();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Class 'SAbc' not found in view

Comment: You have to Include this in view file or write with absolute path. `App\SAbc::count()`. BUT NEVER RUN QUERY IN YOUR VIEW

Comment: Class 'SAbc' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs i am using this method (new SAbc)->getCount();

Comment: You have to include it in your file. `use App\SAbc` or whatever namespace you put your model in